# PHP Dynamically add html code to html file

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic

I am looking for help to dynamically add html code to a html file.

This is an example of what I would like to add to the file:

```
<a rel="lightbox[acc1]" href="myimage.jpg" title="myimage"/>
```

I would like to append this to the stack that uses the lightbox[acc1] element/function,
and I would preferably like to do this with PHP as I wil be using sessions/cookies
with the image links for page admins.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `html` file a `php` file and do this:

```
<?php echo "<a rel=\"lightbox[acc1]\" href=\"myimage.jpg\" title=\"myimage\"/>" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to have your html file be a php file or html which can execute php and then you can run a foreach statement to do it.

```
foreach($_POST['acc1'] as $image){

   echo "<a rel=\"lightbox[acc1]\" href=\"" . $image . "\" title=\"myimage\"/>"


}
```